# Which file does UEFI execute?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, uefi

I would like some clarification on the UEFI booting process. The screen shots below show my current configurations.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I need some clarification on which file UEFI executes. Does UEFI execute /boot/efi/EFI/Ubuntu/grubx64.efi, /boot/efi/EFI/Ubuntu/shimx64.efi, or /boot/efi/EFI/Ubuntu/grub.cfg?

Looking at the contents of /boot/efi/EFI/Ubuntu/grub.cfg, it shows that it points to /boot/grub/grub.cfg which im assuming that this is the file that gets executed. Is that correct?

I appreciate everyones help. Thank you

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). Just copy the output of `tree /boot` and paste here in proper format. That's far more readable, helpful and space saving

Answer (score 2):

`sudo efibootmgr -v` shows exactly what you're looking for.

In case it says `EFI variables are not supported on this system.` you need to `sudo mount -t efivarfs none /sys/firmware/efi/efivars` first.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did run efibootmgr -v as you can see in the last picture. It does say that the file executed is the shimx64.efi but how is that the GRUB? What is the job of shimx64.efi?

Comment: You could literally google for shimx64.efi and find out what it is and what it does. https://github.com/rhboot/shim/ : Initial UEFI bootloader that handles chaining to a trusted full
bootloader under secure boot environments. This package contains the
version signed by the UEFI signing service.

Comment: This answer is on point: what is booted by UEFI is answered by UEFI and can be read this way by efibootmgr (as you noticed yourself). Loading operating systems is typically a process of loading one thing from another, often in several steps. In your case, your UEFI firmware loads the shim, which loads grub2's 1.5th stage, which loads grub2's second stage, which loads your Linux kernel. If you look closer, the process has quite a few more stages; something loads your UEFI firmware, and that typically is also split into at least two stages. Your CPU, before executing any of these loaders, needs

Comment: to load its own initial internal firmware first (this microcode typically gets overwritten partially later on to support patching bugs in the CPU).

Comment: So, always expect booting complex software on complex hardware (*especially* on the legacy and complexity hell that PC-style hardware doing x86 as CPU architecture is) to be a chain of loaded loaders loading the next stage.

Comment: A "shim" is something small that you insert in a gap to make something fit nicely (e.g., a windowframe  in the rectangular hole in a wall  ), so in the context of bootloaders it's just the small piece of software fitting the loader's specifications (here, the UEFI bootloader protocol) to what is needed by the loaded software (here, Grub). It's not doing much! (Here, it just fulfills the requirements of a signed UEFI bootloader, and checks the signature of the grub it loads)

Comment: Note: efibootmgr doesn't need sudo unless you are updating the mapping.

Answer (score 1):

```
BootCurrent: 0002
```

means the system has currently been booted using the UEFI NVRAM boot variable `Boot0002`:

```
Boot0002*  ubuntu       HD(1,GPT,6ed9354d-32d8-427d-b570-d3cb80fe5986,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\Ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
```

That variable defines a boot item titled `ubuntu`, which boots the file `\EFI\Ubuntu\shimx64.efi` from the EFI System Partition (ESP) that has a PARTUUID of `6ed9354d-32d8-427d-b570-d3cb80fe5986`.

So, the firmware loads `shimx64.efi`, which is the Secure Boot compatibility shim. It has been signed using Microsoft's Secure Boot key, which is on the Secure Boot whitelist (known as `db`) on essentially all Secure Boot-capable x86 systems, and so the firmware will allow it to execute.

`shimx64.efi` will non-persistently add Ubuntu's Secure Boot signing key to the allowed list (for this boot only). If a Machine Owner's Key (MOK) has been configured, it will also be added to the Secure Boot whitelist at this point in the same way. Then the shim will tell the firmware to load `grubx64.efi` and attempt to execute it.

`grubx64.efi` is signed using Ubuntu's Secure Boot signing key (to allow Ubuntu to update it without repeating the signing process with Microsoft), and since `shimx64.efi` added that key to the Secure Boot whitelist, the firmware will also allow `grubx64.efi` to execute.

Ubuntu's `grubx64.efi` will load the small `grub.cfg` file from the same directory it is located in. It is not executed, but is read as a data file for `grubx64.efi`. That file will tell GRUB how to find the real GRUB configuration file:

```
search.fs_uuid 8fe7176c-3a23-4902-b0db-14bfbacc6601 root
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

(Translation: find a filesystem with UUID `8fe7176c-3a23-4902-b0db-14bfbacc6601` and designate it as the GRUB root filesystem. Then set the `prefix` variable to `<GRUB root filesystem>/boot/grub`. Then read `grub.cfg` from the directory indicated by the `prefix` variable.)

Finally, GRUB will tell the UEFI firmware to load the Linux kernel and initramfs into memory, and attempt to execute the kernel. If the kernel is also signed with Ubuntu's Secure Boot signing key or MOK, the firmware will allow it to execute, and the Linux kernel starts up. The kernel will read the Secure Boot key whitelist and add it to a special kernel keyring that will be used to check the signature of any kernel modules before executing them. This is a Secure Boot implementation requirement: if anything that is Secure Boot-signed allows non-signed code to execute **in kernel mode**, it will be deemed a "Secure Boot circumvention tool", and it will be blacklisted in future Secure Boot firmware versions and Secure Boot blacklist updates.

Effectively this means only kernel modules that are signed with either the distribution's Secure Boot key or with your MOK will be accepted by the kernel while Secure Boot is enabled. This also means if you try to boot multiple different distributions with a single GRUB while Secure Boot is enabled, you'll need to set up a MOK and sign the kernels of all the distributions (except the one that "owns" the current `shimx64.efi`) with your MOK to allow them to boot.

(In theory, kernel modules signed with Microsoft's Secure Boot key would also be accepted, but unless you work for Microsoft, you are unlikely to be able to have such modules.)

Since the initramfs file is not signed, it is read in by the firmware as non-executable data, but this is not a problem since it needs to be decompressed anyway: the kernel will decompress the initramfs data and move it to a different memory location as part of the boot process anyway. At that point the Linux kernel will have full control of the processor, so it can adjust the execute protection bits of any memory region as it wishes, so executing the decompressed initramfs content **in user mode** (i.e. as regular processes) will be no problem at all.

If kernel modules are loaded from initramfs, they will still be subject to the Secure Boot-mandated signature check.

Answer (score 0):

Any of those files ending in `.efi` are uefi executables and can be run.  Several of them do nearly the same thing -- load the kernel.   Some are signed (for secure boot), some are not.  (See https://askubuntu.com/questions/342365/what-is-the-difference-between-grubx64-and-shimx64 )

Others may be utilities; for example, `mmx64.efi` is the MOK updater utility.

Other files not ending in `.efi` are likely config files.  For example, `grub.cfg` is read by `grubx64.efi`.  Without that, grub couldn't have a built menu without either modifying the grub binary or reading the config file from another location.  The config file, in the context of UEFI, is not executable.  (In an alternate context view, grub.efi is the interpreter that executes the config file.)